# Not able to submit a form onclick of tapestry submit button present outside the form in Tapestry 5.3.2

Tags: forms, submit, tapestry, onsubmit

When i am clicking on tapestry submit present outside the form;form is not getting submitted and throwing an exception

"no object of type FormSupport is avalibale for the Environment".

ALso i am npot able to pass string as context from it to event handler.Please help

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your template and page ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is expected behavior. All form field components, including `Submit`, must be enclosed by a `Form` component.

You can find more information in [the forms sections of the documentation](http://tapestry.apache.org/forms-and-validation.html).